# What's the name of a map where a value V is gotten from a key K which is the biggest key smaller than the requested key?

Tags: javascript, dictionary

Title says it all. For example, if I had a map:

```
{
    4: x,
    7: y
}
```

then, `4` would correspond to `x`, same for 5 and 6, but `7` would be `y`. `3` would be nonexistent.

What kind of map is this? How do I implement it?

Comment: I don't know of a name for this data structure, but it's mapping ranges to values.

Comment: @Barmar thats a way of looking at it. My question is just how to implement it efficiently (enough)

Comment: A sorted array might be best, since you can use binary search. Or a binary tree of some kind.